# How to extract country and city from MKLocalSearchCompletion?

Tags: ios, mapkit

I receive MKLocalSearchCompletion items from MKLocalSearchCompleter to its delegate. Every MKLocalSearchCompletion contains a title and a subtitle, the subtitle is an address. I need to extract a city and a country from the address. Please help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please use the following code:

```
MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
request.naturalLanguageQuery = @"1 Infinite Loop Cupertino, CA 95014"; 
request.region = _mapView.region;
MKLocalSearch *search = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[search startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    //NSLog(@"Map Items: %@", response.mapItems);
    if (response.mapItems.count>0) {
        for (MKMapItem *item in response.mapItems) {
            //NSLog(@"Place: %@",[item valueForKey:@"place"]);
            NSDictionary *dictStructuredAddress = [[[item valueForKey:@"place"] valueForKey:@"address"] valueForKey:@"structuredAddress"];
            NSLog(@"Structured Address : %@",dictStructuredAddress); 
            NSLog(@"Country & City : %@ & %@",[dictStructuredAddress valueForKey@"country"],[dictStructuredAddress valueForKey@"locality"]);
        }
}];
```

Inside this `dictStructuredAddress` you can get country, city, etc.

Comment: It doesn't have such values!

Comment: some : 1 element
    - 0 : <MKMapItem: 0x283d94420> {
    isCurrentLocation = 0;
    name = Chile;
    placemark = "Chile, Chile @ <-34.57297600,-71.09573240> +/- 0.00m, region CLCircularRegion (identifier:'<-39.31833481,-87.92901825> radius 2628724.37', center:<-39.31833481,-87.92901825>, radius:2628724.37m)";
    timeZone = "America/Santiago (GMT-3) offset -10800 (Daylight)";
}

Comment: This is awesome, but I am having trouble converting it to Swift, specifically the dictStructuredAddress with the chained valueForKey.

Comment: @erickva: print only `item["place"]` then you will get the actual keys.

Comment: @Poles what I found impossible was to parse the keys returned from item["place"], weirdly.

Answer (score 4):

MKLocalSearchCompletion does not "contain an address". It contains a title and subtitle. To get more information, use the MKLocalSearchCompletion to form an MKLocalSearchRequest and perform the MKLocalSearch.